# I2P latest installer asks for Java 5

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

So I'm trying to install [I2P](http://geti2p.net/en/download), which requires a JRE to run. I already have Java 6 and 7 JREs installed, yet the damn installer asks for, of all things, Java 5, and then very 'helpfully' pops open a browser window to the Java download page!! I snooped on its registry access using Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), then cheated by creating a registry key for Java 5 at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.5` with the same content as the key for 1.6, i.e. 2 strings for `JavaHome` and `RuntimeLib`.

I suspect someone got sloppy with their installer version checking code because I2P documentation clearly says it supports Java 6, and 5, which was launched a decade ago, isn't available on the Oracle Java download page anymore.

Anyone else face this problem and do you have a workaround that doesn't involve hunting for and installing JRE 1.5.0? I can't ask on the I2P forums because guess what, they're accessible only over the I2P network!

Comment: Howdy! Did you find a fix? Cheers!

Comment: Nope..I can't uninstall the 64bit Java 6 that I have as default since it's required for other things I'm working on. Tried hacking around the registry to change the version read by the installer but no luck.

Comment: My win 8.1 config doesn't work even if I had installed JRE 1.5 :-((

Answer (score 3):

I2P is meant to work with Java 6 and 7; we recommend JRE 7, and are going to drop Java 5 support in the next release. This is likely a Windows-specific bug, possibly even 8.1-specific as we have not had any prior reports. And I think the cause is our executable wrapper (Launch4J) not detecting 64-bit JREs properly. Are you using 64-bit JREs?

[I have filed a ticket on our bugtracker for this](https://trac.i2p2.de/ticket/1205).
If you have any additional comments, please add them there :)

(And BTW, the I2P IRC channels are relayed to Freenode and OFTC, so #i2p #i2p-dev #i2p-help on those networks will reach us.)

Comment: I have several JDKs installed, but the default JRE is 1.6.0.37, 64-bit. (i.e. what you get when you type `java -version` at the command prompt).

Comment: I've created an account there as rex, but see no option to add a further comment once I'm logged in. Do I need permissions to comment?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Ticket creation and comments are restricted because of repeated spamming *sigh* For future reference, users can ask in #i2p-dev to be given permission. Both your accounts now have permission to comment :)

Comment: How do I login with my account?